# Accessing dynamic resource message

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, internationalization

In my Jsp i am having radio buttons for

```
typeA

typeB

typeC

typeD
```

I have used following tag :

```
<c:forEach var="abcTyp" items="${abcTypeList}">
    <form:radiobutton path="abcType" value="<spring:message code="label.admin.lot.${abcType.value}" />" label="${abcTyp.value}" onclick="actSingStone();"/>
</c:forEach>
```

but instead of using "abcTyp.value" as a label,i want to use internationalized message form resource bundle .

I tried using

```
<form:radiobuttons path="abcType" value="${abcTypeList}" label="<spring:message code="label.admin.pep.${abcTyp.value}"/>." onclick="actSingStone();"/>
```

in my resource file i have mentioned

```
label.admin.pep.typeA = some text
label.admin.pep.typeB = some text
label.admin.pep.typeC = some text
label.admin.pep.typeD = some text
```

but it's giving an error "equal symbol expected"

Can anybody give me solution for the same....??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the label to variable and use it, like below

```
<c:forEach var="abcTyp" items="${abcTypeList}">
  <c:set var="labelVar">
      <spring:message code="label.admin.lot.${abcType.value}" />
  </c:set>    
  <form:radiobutton path="abcType" label="${labelVar}" value="${abcTyp.value}" onclick="actSingStone();"/>    
</c:forEach>
```